# Runtime Statistics in Python

Tags: python, logging, analytics

I'm looking for a library for gathering "runtime statistics" in python, by which I mean an interface for outputting structured log files.  A good example of what I would like is Twitter's [ostrich](https://github.com/twitter/ostrich) project in Scala, wherein one simply executes a statement notifying the logger of an event.  Ideally, this would then be automatically aggregated into a suitable visualization for application monitoring.

Does anyone know if such a library exists?  Alternatively, does anyone know a more generic way of combining traditional message logging with some simply graphing for runtime analytics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) is one such system, written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ostrich, but a quick look at the readme suggests that the python project [`mmstats`](https://github.com/schmichael/mmstats) might be close to what you're looking for.